# Find $E(X)$ and $E(Y)$ where $-X\overset{d}{=} X$ and $X^2\overset{d}{=} \frac{Z}{Z+W}$ where Z ~ Gamma(1) and W ~ Gamma(2)

Tags: self-study, expected-value

Suppose $-X\overset{d}{=} X$ and $X^2\overset{d}{=} \frac{Z}{Z+W}$ where Z ~ Gamma(1) and W ~ Gamma(2) and Z is independant of W. Also suppose $Y = \frac{X}{\sqrt{1 - X^2}}$.

I have to find the following values: $E(|X|)$, $E(X)$ and $E(Y)$.

Here is my attempt at a solution:

$$E(|X|) = \frac{E\sqrt{Z}}{E\sqrt{Z+W}} = \frac{\Gamma(3/2)/\Gamma(1)}{\Gamma(7/2)/\Gamma(3)} = \frac{2! \cdot \sqrt{\pi}/2}{(5/2)(3/2)(\sqrt{\pi}/2)} = 8/15$$

This part I know to be correct as it matches the solutions provided to me.

However, calculating $E(X)$ is where my problems begin. The answer says that $E(X) = 0$, but I am unsure how they arrived at that answer.

As for $E(Y)$, the answer also says that $E(Y) = 0$. However, I am also stuck on how to get there. I know the following:

$$Y = \frac{X}{\sqrt{1 - X^2}} \implies Y\sqrt{1 - X^2} = X \implies  E(Y\sqrt{1 - X^2}) = E(X) = 0$$

However, I don't know if $Y$ and $\sqrt{1 - X^2}$ are independent of each other, so I don't know how to break apart $E(Y\sqrt{1 - X^2})$.

I'd appreciate any suggestions on how I can solve these two questions.

Comment: Where did you define $T$? What does $-X\stackrel{d}{=}X$ tell you about $X$?

Comment: @Glen_b: apologies, T = Z+W and $-X \overset{d}{=} X$ would tell me they're equal in distribution and presumably their expectations are the same.

Comment: @Cici Thanks for the edit. Think a little more about using that information about $X$ to get $E(X)$

Comment: @Glen_b Hmm thanks for the hint! Let me know if you have one for EY

Comment: Can you apply the same trick you used for X?